# Is there a linear-time algorithm for finding the convex hull of a complex polygon?

Tags: algorithm, polygon, time-complexity, convex-hull

I know there's a worst-case O(n log n) algorithm for finding the convex hull of a complex polygon and a worst-case O(n) algorithm for finding the convex hull of a simple polygon.  Is there a worst-case O(n) algorithm for finding the convex hull of a complex polygon?

A complex polygon is a polygon where the line segments may intersect.  Finding the convex hull of a complex polygon is equivalent to finding the convex hull of an unordered list of points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your point sets are such that some non-comparison based sorting mechanism (like radix sort) will be faster than comparison based methods, then it seems you can use the Graham scan algorithm (http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/72_10_convex_hull.pdf) to compute it. The time complexity of the Graham scan is dominated by the sorting step. The rest is linear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure not.  Convex hull on arbitrary point sets can be shown to be equivalent to sorting.  We can order an arbitrary point set and connect the points in sequence making it into a *complex polygon*, thereby reducing the problem on arbitrary point sets to yours.

Here is a link to a [proof](http://www.cs.pitt.edu/~kirk/cs1510/notes/reducenotes.pdf) that convex hull is equivalent to sorting.  I'm too damn lazy and too bad a typist to write it out myself.

Comment: The proof relies on the idea that sorting takes at least O(n log n).  However, that's only true of comparison-based sorting.  Since points are integers or floats, we have many more operations available than simply comparisons.  In particular, radix sort can sort points in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no there is not a O(n) solution.  There is a pixelated version that is better than O(n log n).  It is, however, so hobbled in other ways that you'd be crazy to use it in practice.

You render the first polygon (using verts 0, 1, 2) into screen space, then re-render the verts themselves using a distinct ID so they can be identified later.  For example, you might clear the frame buffer to RGBA ffffffff and use fffffffe for space that is covered by the convex hull.  Each vertex would be rendered using its ID as its RGBA; 00000000, 00000001, etc.

A 16-bit example:

```
fffffffffffffff
fffffff0fffffff
ffffffeeeffffff
fffffeeeeefffff
ffffeeeeeeeffff
fffeeeeeeeeefff
ff2eeeeeeeee1ff
fffffffffffffff
```

Checking a new point is a simple lookup in the current frame buffer.  If the pixel it occupies is 'shaded' with polygon or with a vertex ID, the new vertex is rejected.

If the new vertex is outside the existing polygon, you find the first pixel between the new vertex and some point inside the convex hull (something in the middle of the first poly works fine) and march along the circumference of the hull - in both directions - until you find yourself on the far side of the hull from the new vertex.  (I'll leave this as an exercise to the user.  There are plenty of solutions that all suck, from an efficiency perspective.)  Fill in the poly defined by these two points and the new vertex with the ID for polygon space - being careful not to erase any vertex IDs - and go on to the next pixel.

When you're done, any pixel which contains a vertex ID that is not completely surrounded by hull IDs is a convex hull vertex.

While the algorithm's complexity is O(n) with the number of vertices, it's deficiencies are obvious.  **Nobody in their right mind would use it unless they had a ridiculous, insane, staggering number of points** to process so that nearly every vertex would be immediately rejected, and unless they could accept the limitation of an aliased result.

Friends don't let friends implement this algorithm.

Comment: It sounds like when the algorithm adds a vertex (which it must do O(n) times), it must march along the circumference of the hull-so-far (which will take O(n) time).  Isn't that O(n**2)?  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the algorithm.

Comment: Nope.  The circumference is bounded by the size of the frame buffer, and its traversal's complexity is not affected by the number of vertexes in it - only the number of pixels it contains.  It takes the same ammount of time to trace a frame buffers of the same size with 3 verts and 3,000,000 verts.

Comment: @user30997: I see.  If we treat the size of the frame buffer in pixels (p) as a variable rather than a constant, what is the time complexity in terms of n and p?

Comment: If n is the number of verts and the frame buffer is p pixels on a side then, given that the longest traverse you could ever make of the circumference of the convex hull is 2p, you have a complexity of 2np.  n, being independent of p, gives a Big-O time complexity of O(n).  However, the cost-per-operation is extremely high, so the algorithm is only useful to a narrow subset of applications.  This isn't unusual in algorithms: consider, for example, the "almost sorted" list where you know that no item is out of place by more than one position.  The sorting complexity there is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If your points come from a finite universe (which is always the case in practice) you can do radix sort and then run Andrew's monotone chain algorithm.